Windows 10: Programmatically preload user profile (before login)
I have code that records the screen display and camera output using https://github.com/sskodje/ScreenRecorderLib which in turn uses the native Microsoft Media Foundation. Since services run in session 0 which is not linked to a functional display device, I cannot run this code as a service.
To give some context: the code needs to run in the background, regardless of active user sessions. In other words, it must work even when no user is logged in and continue to record through sign out/switch user events.
The use case is a lecture hall where lecturers may or may not log in at any point of their lecture. Obviously, if they want their screen display to be recorded, they'll log in but sometimes, they only want the cam and audio to be captured and therefore, do not log in at all.
In Windows 10, if I add the app under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and restart, it is preloaded once the machine reboots (shortly after logonui is launched and starts recording (which is the desired behaviour). However, the preloading only happens if the restart was made while the user was logged in. If I log the user out and then restart, preloading of the user profile does not occur.
Is there a way to programmatically perform this preload operation (or any other that will result in same/similar behaviour) from service context or a startup script or a scheduled task?
I am aware of the auto-login option and realise I could lock the desktop of the user I auto login after running the app there but the problem with that is that when a different user logs in, that app will malfunction. Whereas, with the preloading feature, the process just exits gracefully and is restarted under the newly logged user (because of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run).
I don't normally code on Windows (a UNIX guy, with Linux as my main OS) but I have made an effort to research this and could not find an obvious solution. If there are other options that will allow me to accomplish the end goal (as stated above), I'll be most happy to learn about them (maybe a low level capture API that can work with no active user sessions?).
I was told that Echo360 is capable of running this way on Windows 10 and while I do not have access to that software, https://support.echo360.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035404751-EchoVideo-Device-Monitor-Overview-Administrators does state:

The EchoVideo Device Service is a service-level version of the Device Monitor software that does not require a user to be logged into the podium PC

Thanks in advance for any pointers,
